# Azure ServiceFabric ImageStoreService fault

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I deployed this 2 node type cluster in Azure, with an enabled reverse proxy, and waited for it to deploy - cluster has 10 nodes, instance count of 5 for both node types....when I connected the system explorer after 45 min... why would this system service be failing? I have not deployed the application yet....

[image: ImageSToreServicefault]

Comment: Is not possible to  help with just this screenshot. Can you check in which nodes are these services deployed, connect to the Machine and check the Windows EventLogs, it will probably show the detailed error message. Make sure that the nodes has enough disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same problem - same two failing system services. From what I have been able to gather, it is a lack of disk space issue. What size of VMs are you using?

I had more failing services in quorum-loss state to begin with. Restarting the Virtual Machine Scale Set resolved most of these problems, but not FaultAnalysisService and ImageStoreService. Surely it should be possible to run a cluster on the smallest of VMs offered in Azure...

Comment: Yup.. opened a ticket and that was the resolution.. need at least 14gig of space and I won lottery picking 4gig... Wasn't the cheapest either as I know they make those very limited.

Comment: It would make sense that they only show vms in list that will actually work with Service fabric!